# Setting Heroku config vars that contain the special character $

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to set a Heroku config variable that contains the special character `$` but I do not know how to properly escape it. I tried encapsulating it in quotes but got the same result.

Example:

```
heroku config:set EMAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx$xxxxxxxx
=> EMAIL_PASSWORD: xxxxx

heroku config:set EMAIL_PASSWORD="xxxxx$xxxxxxxx"
=> EMAIL_PASSWORD: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming you are using Bash (which is likely if you are on Mac or Linux) you can use single quotes to escape strings with `$`, or use `\`:

```
$ echo $FOO

$ echo "$FOO"

$ echo '$FOO'
$FOO
$ echo \$FOO
$FOO
```

Comment: Spent half day pulling out my hair on this... need to do the same for config vars beginning with '@'