# Django SECRET_KEY error due to containing "!" in secret key

Tags: django, bash, heroku, environment-variables

I'm trying to deploy my django application in heroku. While deploying it seems that i need to set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY manually in `heroku config:set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=secretekey` instead environment variablele file. But i'm getting the error `bash event not found` . I know this is due to exclamation mark in SECRET_KEY. I've tried using single and double quotes but that too didn't work.

This is the part of my SECRET_KEY causing error,

```
 (+9=!sbeh**************
```

EDIT:
i'm using platformio-ide-terminal in ubuntu

Comment: I suggest to add single quotes (`'`).

Comment: tried using both single and double quotes

Comment: Try escaping with a slash: `heroku config:set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY="(+9=\!sbeh**************"`

Comment: solved: I've changed the terminal into default ubuntu terminal and single quotes( ' ) works fine. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this in your .env file

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='<secret_key>'
```

or

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=\<secret_key>
```

Comment: while using .env file ,it works fine in locally. the problem is while deploying heroku

Comment: Did you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417501/setting-heroku-config-vars-that-contain-the-special-character)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem when deploying to Heroku, the simplest solution is to set the config variable using Heroku's web interface.

Go to your project settings

```
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<project-name>/settings
```

Click on config vars at the bottom.
You can set any config there as key:value pair.

*PS: The problem is with bash shell interpreting characters like "&", "!", etc as special characters.*